# conditional probability P(X=m+n|X>=m)

Tags: probability

[image: Put a bang before it.]

For question a, I know that for $P(X=m+n)$ is just plugging in $x=m+n$, but I am not able to compute $P(X\geq m)$, if I didn't get it wrongly, it should be something like summation of probability from m to infinity or 1-P(from 0 to m-1).  But I am not able to simplify the answer by myself.

$$\mathsf P(X\geq m)~=~\sum_{k=0}^\infty \mathsf P(X=m+k)$$

For question b, I simply don't know what to comment/compare. Maybe more hints can be given to me to let me think.

Comment: Hint: $$\sum_{x=m}^\infty p^x=p^m\sum_{k=0}^\infty p^k=\frac{p^m}{1-p}$$

Answer (score 1):

As Did said, use the Geometric Series to simplify.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X\geq m)~&=~\sum_{k=0}^\infty \mathsf P(X=m+k)\\[1ex]&=~\sum_{k=1}^\infty p(1-p)^{m+k}\end{align} $$

Then as you appear to know: $$\mathsf P(X=m+n\mid X\geq m) = \dfrac{\mathsf P(X=m+n)}{\mathsf P(X\geq m)}$$

Once you have found that, the comparison to $\mathsf P(X=n)$ is rather obvious.

---

As to commenting, ask: What can you interpret the $p$ to represent?

Comment: With your help, I am now able to find that the relationship should be equal. Yet, what else can I comment on their relationship?

Comment: Well, $P(X=m+n\mid X\geq m)=P(X=n)$ means that after you sell some items, the probability of selling *$n$ more* items in the rest of the day *equals* the probability you had of selling *$n$* items that day at the start of the day.  *In short* the future demand in that day is independent of earlier supply.